# Strange behavior of Select element depending on DOM order

Tags: angularjs

Here is my controller:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('Controller1', function($scope) {
        $scope.selected_country = "";
        $scope.countries = [{
            id: 'US',
            desc: 'United States'
        }, {
            id: 'GB',
            desc: 'United Kingdom'
        }];
    });
```

Here is a working html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
</head>
<body ng-controller="Controller1">

  <div>Selected Country: {{selected_country}} </div>

  <form name="myForm">
    <select name=country" ng-model="selected_country"
            ng-options="country.id as country.desc for country in countries"
    </select>
  </form>

  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But if I put `<div>` after `<select>`:

```
  <form name="myForm">
    <select name=country" ng-model="selected_country"
            ng-options="country.id as country.desc for country in countries"
    </select>
  </form>

  <div>Selected Country: {{selected_country}} </div>
```

This `<div>` just disappeared from browser.  Why?

Comment: you haven't got a closing bracket on your select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a quote and an angle bracket.

```
<select name=country" ng-model="selected_country"
        ng-options="country.id as country.desc for country in countries"
```

should be

```
<select name="country" ng-model="selected_country"
            ng-options="country.id as country.desc for country in countries">
```